# How to remove default margins of View, SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI. According to my picture below, there are leading and trailing margins appeared in my DialogView(white area at bottom). I need to remove it.

[image]

Here's my code.

```
struct ForgetPasswordView: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image("img_test").resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
            .frame(height: 130)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            
            Spacer()
            DialogView()
                .background(Color.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .padding(.top, 120)
        .background(Color.pink)
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct DialogView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
        Text("Forget Password")
            .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .light))
            .padding(.top, 20)
        Text("Proceed to reset your password? ")
            .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .light))
        Text("If yes, please enter your existing mobile number to receive OTP")
            .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .light) )
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that want to keep the background of the `DialogView` to ignore the safe area but keep its content within the safe area.

In this case use a ZStack with a `fixedSize` modifier like this:

```swift
struct DialogView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
                Text("Forget Password")
                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .light))
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                Text("Proceed to reset your password? ")
                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .light))
                Text("If yes, please enter your existing mobile number to receive OTP")
                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .light) )
            }
        }
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}
```

Also, you'll need to remove existing `.background` and `.frame` that you add in the parent view and embed it just like `DialogView()`.

Comment: It solves the issue. I didn't know there  are safe area in leading and trailing as well in SwiftUI.

Comment: Actually, in this particular case the leading and trailing safe area margins are zero, it's just the VStack tends to occupy as little space as possible to wrap its content, but if you rotate the phone to landscape, you'll get non-zero horizontal and vertical safe area margins. I'd also suggest to add a `.padding` to VStack so that it's guaranteed that it won't be too close to the screen edges in portrait.

Comment: I will put padding. This is juz raw.